# Get OneDrive data for Microsoft Azure Users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Trying to get response for [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drives](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser_id%7D/drives) but get:
{'error': {'code': 'ResourceNotFound',
'message': "User's mysite not found.",}

Permissions is ok, user_id is correct

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error on my side, and found that, if I used ropc flow to generate an access token and used a different user id in request, it then returned 'User's mysite not found'. And if I used credential flow with a user id which doesn't has one drive license, it then returned that error. If I used correct user id which has one drive license, 200 code returned. And the [api doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#path-parameters) also mentioned that 'idOrUserPrincipalName    string  Required. The identifier for the user object **who owns the OneDrive**'

So my idea is check the user id if you used password flow to generate the access token and if not, you should make sure the user to tested via the api has the correct license.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you get any progress? Pls feel free to let us know if you got any further problems.